Design matrix in R after altering the data
Consider the following code where we fit a regression model, alter the data and create the corresponding design matrix for the altered data based on the fitted regression model:
mtcars_alt <- mtcars |>
  dplyr::mutate(vs = factor(vs),
                am = factor(am))

mod_lm <- lm(mpg ~ vs*am, data = mtcars_alt)
mtcars_alt |>
  dplyr::mutate(am = "0") |>
  model.matrix(mod_lm, data = _)

mod_glm <- glm(mpg ~ vs*am, data = mtcars_alt)
mtcars_alt |>
  dplyr::mutate(am = "0") |>
  model.matrix(mod_glm, data = _)

When the regression model is based on lm() then it works fine, however, it throws an error when it's based on glm()
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Any idea how to circumvent this error?

IMO, the actual issue here is that no error is thrown for the "lm" model. Why are you doing this?

@Roland: I'm implementing a statistical method for which I need to do some post-hoc computations which involve such altered design matrices.

It seems that the insight package has a function get_modelmatrix() which creates a work around by padding empty levels before passing it to model.matrix().

If you call model.matrix() on the GLM's formula rather than the model object itself and create the constant factor am as a factor with two levels (even though only one is observed, as suggested by @Stefan Hansen in the comments), you should get the desired result.
mtcars_alt <- mtcars |>
  dplyr::mutate(vs = factor(vs),
                am = factor(am))

mod_glm <- glm(mpg ~ vs*am, data = mtcars_alt)
mtcars_alt |>
  dplyr::mutate(am = factor("0", levels=c("0", "1"))) |>
  model.matrix(formula(mod_glm), data = _)
#>                     (Intercept) vs1 am1 vs1:am1
#> Mazda RX4                     1   0   0       0
#> Mazda RX4 Wag                 1   0   0       0
#> Datsun 710                    1   1   0       0
#> Hornet 4 Drive                1   1   0       0
#> Hornet Sportabout             1   0   0       0
#> Valiant                       1   1   0       0
#> Duster 360                    1   0   0       0
#> Merc 240D                     1   1   0       0
#> Merc 230                      1   1   0       0
#> Merc 280                      1   1   0       0
#> Merc 280C                     1   1   0       0
#> Merc 450SE                    1   0   0       0
#> Merc 450SL                    1   0   0       0
#> Merc 450SLC                   1   0   0       0
#> Cadillac Fleetwood            1   0   0       0
#> Lincoln Continental           1   0   0       0
#> Chrysler Imperial             1   0   0       0
#> Fiat 128                      1   1   0       0
#> Honda Civic                   1   1   0       0
#> Toyota Corolla                1   1   0       0
#> Toyota Corona                 1   1   0       0
#> Dodge Challenger              1   0   0       0
#> AMC Javelin                   1   0   0       0
#> Camaro Z28                    1   0   0       0
#> Pontiac Firebird              1   0   0       0
#> Fiat X1-9                     1   1   0       0
#> Porsche 914-2                 1   0   0       0
#> Lotus Europa                  1   1   0       0
#> Ford Pantera L                1   0   0       0
#> Ferrari Dino                  1   0   0       0
#> Maserati Bora                 1   0   0       0
#> Volvo 142E                    1   1   0       0
#> attr(,"assign")
#> [1] 0 1 2 3
#> attr(,"contrasts")
#> attr(,"contrasts")$vs
#> [1] "contr.treatment"
#> 
#> attr(,"contrasts")$am
#> [1] "contr.treatment"

Created on 2024-11-14 with reprex v2.1.0

Nice -- that works! Thanks.
